# how delete record in a polymorphic association using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations, delete-row

I am trying to create an activity stream so my model looks like

```
class CreateFeeds < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :feeds do |t|
      t.integer :item_id
      t.string :item_type
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item, polymorphic: true
end
```

I have added this to my post controller

```
feed_item @post
```

and this to my application controller

```
def feed_item(item, action = params[:action])
   current_user.feeds.create! action: action, item: item
end
```

I am displaying my post content like

```
= feed.item.text
```

my problem is when I call

```
= link_to "delete", feed.item, method: :delete
```

I delete the feed item but the reference to the item remain in the database and I get

error: missing template "delete"

unless I add if present?

How can I this reference to an item?

Comment: can you show us the controller action for "delete"?

Comment: I think you are describing two problems which we will fix separately. 1) the "missing template" 2) that the reference hangs around.

Comment: Why does a feed belong to an item, and not the other way around? Surely a feed has more than one item... ?

Comment: I am calling destroy as normally for each item. for example in post controller's destroy action I call @post.destroy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is simply deleting the item, with no impact on the feed. I think you need to either:

- Explicitly clear the `item_type` and `item_id` references in `feed` (e.g. by implementing a `remove_item` method in your Feed controller and model), or
- If your domain would allow for it, change your `belongs_to` association to a `has_one` association, with corresponding changes to your database. In that case, deleting the item wouldn't require any changes to the associated feed.

As an aside, it's unusual to keep your migration in with your model definition. The migration should really be in a separate file.

Comment: I thing is I am trying to reference many items, but you first point seem like could work, but how cant I implement it so it is called when I call delete on the item?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "reference items", but as I said, you can implement the first approach by implementing item deletion in your Feed controller and model. In other words, instead of calling delete in your Item controller, you would need to call delete_item in your Feed controller, which would call the same method name in your Feed model.

Comment: I am calling delete like feed.item.destroy so how can I make sure the feed's item_type and item_id are destroyed as well?

Comment: You cannot implement it by calling `feed.item.destroy` because the `item` object doesn't know anything about the `item` field of `feed`. That's the essence of my answer. I'm telling you that you must do something else (i.e. either clear the `item` field separately or implement a new method to do both).

Comment: @TarynEast How would that help? The OP wants to retain the feed.